# How to parse Json object with nested Json array response

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, gson

I am new to Api stuff in Android.i have worked on Api response with Json object but not with nested ones. i am confused how to do it with nested Json array in Json object.i saw some tutorials but still confused.

For Eg. below is my Json response:

```
    {
  "results": {
    "next": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03NzgzMWY5My1hMTc3LTU1MzYtOTc0YS1lYjcyYTBmMGZjN2NfMTUzODMzOTIxMDExM184NTM0XzU0MzUmb2Zmc2V0PTIwJnNpemU9MjA?at=37.7942%2C-122.407&q=police-emergency&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
    "items": [
      {
        "position": [
          37.79855,
          -122.40986
        ],
        "distance": 545,
        "title": "San Francisco Police Dept-Central",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "police-station",
          "title": "Police Station",
          "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places/police-station?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/19.icon",
        "vicinity": "766 Vallejo St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94133",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8409q8zn-a0b398e1a4664f458efe8a4cd3115bc5;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03NzgzMWY5My1hMTc3LTU1MzYtOTc0YS1lYjcyYTBmMGZjN2NfMTUzODMzOTIxMDExM184NTM0XzU0MzUmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
        "id": "8409q8zn-a0b398e1a4664f458efe8a4cd3115bc5",
        "alternativeNames": [
          {
            "name": "Central District Police Station",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "name": "Police Department",
            "language": "en"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "position": [
          37.79158,
          -122.40228
        ],
        "distance": 507,
        "title": "Wang & Wang",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "police-station",
          "title": "Police Station",
          "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places/police-station?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/19.icon",
        "vicinity": "250 Montgomery St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94104",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-18f83a71fbab46c0b04fc2838ebf7867;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03NzgzMWY5My1hMTc3LTU1MzYtOTc0YS1lYjcyYTBmMGZjN2NfMTUzODMzOTIxMDExM184NTM0XzU0MzUmcmFuaz0x?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
        "id": "8409q8yy-18f83a71fbab46c0b04fc2838ebf7867",
        "openingHours": {
          "text": "Mon-Fri: 08:30 - 17:00",
          "label": "Opening hours",
          "isOpen": false,
          "structured": [
            {
              "start": "T083000",
              "duration": "PT08H30M",
              "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR"
            }
          ]
        }
      },

      {
        "position": [
          37.78366,
          -122.4129
        ],
        "distance": 1282,
        "title": "San Francisco Police-Tenderloin",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "police-station",
          "title": "Police Station",
          "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places/police-station?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/19.icon",
        "vicinity": "301 Eddy St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94102",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-d7bbb787aa58418c917d531a5b2a51b0;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03NzgzMWY5My1hMTc3LTU1MzYtOTc0YS1lYjcyYTBmMGZjN2NfMTUzODMzOTIxMDExM184NTM0XzU0MzUmcmFuaz0xNA?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
        "id": "8409q8yy-d7bbb787aa58418c917d531a5b2a51b0",
        "alternativeNames": [
          {
            "name": "Police Department",
            "language": "en"
          },
          {
            "name": "SFPD - Tenderloin Station",
            "language": "en"
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "position": [
          37.81885,
          -122.26497
        ],
        "distance": 12775,
        "title": "Vigelant Pro Private Security",
        "averageRating": 0,
        "category": {
          "id": "police-emergency",
          "title": "Police/Emergency",
          "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places/police-emergency?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
          "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
          "system": "places"
        },
        "icon": "https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/19.icon",
        "vicinity": "411 30th St<br/>Oakland, CA 94609",
        "having": [],
        "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
        "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8403fv6k-0c72e65d7d660fb3b53e5021d92b1283;context=Zmxvdy1pZD03NzgzMWY5My1hMTc3LTU1MzYtOTc0YS1lYjcyYTBmMGZjN2NfMTUzODMzOTIxMDExM184NTM0XzU0MzUmcmFuaz0xOQ?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
        "id": "8403fv6k-0c72e65d7d660fb3b53e5021d92b1283"
      }
    ]
  },
  "search": {
    "context": {
      "location": {
        "position": [
          37.7942,
          -122.407
        ],
        "address": {
          "text": "818 Clay St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94108<br/>USA",
          "house": "818",
          "street": "Clay St",
          "postalCode": "94108",
          "district": "Chinatown",
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "county": "San Francisco",
          "stateCode": "CA",
          "country": "United States",
          "countryCode": "USA"
        }
      },
      "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
      "href": "https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPTgxOCtDbGF5K1N0O2xhdD0zNy43OTQyO2xvbj0tMTIyLjQwNztzdHJlZXQ9Q2xheStTdDtob3VzZT04MTg7Y2l0eT1TYW4rRnJhbmNpc2NvO3Bvc3RhbENvZGU9OTQxMDg7Y291bnRyeT1VU0E7ZGlzdHJpY3Q9Q2hpbmF0b3duO3N0YXRlQ29kZT1DQTtjb3VudHk9U2FuK0ZyYW5jaXNjbztjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWJ1aWxkaW5nO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbA;context=c2VhcmNoQ29udGV4dD0x?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg"
    },
    "supportsPanning": true,
    "ranking": "category-recommendations"
  }
}
```

I know that the outer curly bracket means object and other box bracket is json array but i am confused how to parse it.. I use Retrofit lib tho

#### **Update:**

I tried using POJO but when i debug the app the break point breaks at ApiInterface Object creation with out any message. Earlier i got null in body without any error(I had hardcoded the value which i want to pass in @PATH ).

```
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<Results> call = apiService.getALlData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Results>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Results> call, Response<Results> response) {


                ArrayList<Item> items = response.body().getItems();
                rc.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Results> call, Throwable t) {

            }


        });
```

- When i try to use @Path with value my Url gives error (must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.)

my URL:  https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at={LAT/LONG}&q=police-emergency&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={AP_CODE}

My implementation which leads is not working.

```
   @GET("search?at={latlong}&q=police-emergency&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id=********&app_code=**********")
Call<Results> getAllData(@Path("") String s);
```

Any Concept or help would be appreciated.. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Essentially you can have Objects within Objects. In this situation, your response returns an Object with two keys: `results`, and `search`. Those then lead  to more Objects. So now if you access `APIResponse['results']` you will get back the Object in `results` which has keys i.e. `next`, `items` etc. It's a nested tree in ways. Not sure if that helps?

Comment: Use GSON and convert the current japn output. Using GSON at these situations is the best choice.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of GSON--I prefer to create my own parser; but in this case I would agree with  ʍѳђઽ૯ท . GSON appears to be the best choice for this rather complex JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Json arrays are parsed as ArrayList, for your code you need something like this:

```
public class QueryResult {
    private Results results;
    private Search search;
    /* getters and setters */

}

class Results{
    private String next;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;
    /* getters and setters */
}

class Item{
    private ArrayList<Float> position;
    private int distance;
    private String title;
    private int averageRating;
    private Category category;
    (...)

}
```

Then you need to create a Category object with its fields and so on.

Finally you can make a retrofit call:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<QueryResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<QueryResult> call, Response<QueryResult> response) {
                QueryResult result = response.body()
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<QueryResult> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer..I just need the values of title, position (array) and distance ..i wanted to know how to access the values of possition using retrofit. Cuz possition is an array so i was confused here.. as on callback we are passing endpoint of queryresult how to access these above datas in this call back .. i may make a list for title and distance object but what about position ..how get it..please help...Thankyou.